# About functions naming, what 'Generic' stand for function name 'helloGCSGeneric'

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, naming

My question is about what stand for naming like 'Generic'.

I'm looking through GCP's cloud function tutorial, 
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/storage#object_finalize

There's simple example on this tutorial.

```
/**
 * Generic background Cloud Function to be triggered by Cloud Storage.
 *
 * @param {object} event The Cloud Functions event.
 * @param {function} callback The callback function.
 */
exports.helloGCSGeneric = (data, context, callback) => {
  const file = data;

  console.log(`  Event: ${context.eventId}`);
  console.log(`  Event Type: ${context.eventType}`);
  console.log(`  Bucket: ${file.bucket}`);
  console.log(`  File: ${file.name}`);
  console.log(`  Metageneration: ${file.metageneration}`);
  console.log(`  Created: ${file.timeCreated}`);
  console.log(`  Updated: ${file.updated}`);

  callback();
};
```

What this function does is easy enough even for me.
It's triggered when object creation/update finalized in my understanding.

'helloGCSFinalization', or 'helloGCSGeneration' makes sense, but why is it named like 'Generic'?
In which situation 'Generic' is used? I think it's different from the one in programming language such as C++ or Java.

This question sounds silly, but no way English is not my mother tongue, still I'd like to grasp a big picture of this naming context.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This very interesting question. I wander who else would try to anwser...

I am not English native speaker too, but I will try to resolve it that way: As this is Google documentation I tried to use [Google Translator](https://translate.google.pl/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=generic).

And first description of this Generic term is(at least on my side:)):

> characteristic of or relating to a class or group of things; not
>   specific.

Among synonyms you may find: general, common, non-specific.

Of course I can only guess, but I think that author had on his mind: "just simply function triggered Google Cloud Storage". Although I agree that there is such term in [computer programming theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_function).

This is just my voice in the case...

Comment: "Among synonyms you may find: general, common, non-specific." this seems like whole explanation and it's enough for vague understanding for me. Thanks for givin' me clue @vitooh!